# Locally published C# API not getting values from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, publish, appsettings, .net-7.0

I wanted to run metrics against my .NET 7 API. To do so, I read, to get the most accurate metrics, I should publish it. But, when I do, my application is not getting the values from my `appsettings.json`.

Both my `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.development.json` look like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "MongoDbOptions": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost",
    "DatabaseName": "testDb"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationOptions": {
    "ShowExceptions": true,
    "ValidateQuery": true
  }
}
```

In my `Program.cs` file, I configure them via:

```
builder.Services.Configure<MongoDbOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MongoDbOptions)));
builder.Services.Configure<ApplicationOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ApplicationOptions)));
```

They are injected into the code via:
`IOptions<ApplicationOptions> applicationOptions` and `IOptions<MongoDbOptions> mongoDbOptions`.

Everything works fine when I run the API in VS Code. I can run queries against my local mongo db and I can access the values of the `ApplicationOptions`.

In a console running as Admin, I publish it locally via:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o ./bin/Publish
```

Then, run it:

```
dotnet D:\GitLocal/CrudMetrics/bin/Publish/CrudMetrics.Api.dll --urls "https://localhost:7279"
```

When I call a route via Postman that hits my local mongo db, I get this error:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConfigurationException: The connection string '' is not valid.

To test that it was getting any value from the `appsettings.json`, in my controller where `IOptions<ApplicationOptions> applicationOptions` is injected into, I instantly throw an exception to see if I get the value from the application options.

```
throw new Exception($"Value of _applicationOptions.ShowExceptions:{_applicationOptions.ShowExceptions}.");
```

This returns this error:

> System.Exception: Value of _applicationOptions.ShowExceptions:False.

Obviously, it is fine that it is an error, but you can see that `ShowExceptions` is false, but in the `appsettings.json` it is true.

I can see both the `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.development.json` files are in the same directory as the `CrudMetrics.Api.dll` file. If I open them in Notepad, I can see the correct, expected values that are above and also used when running it via VS Code.

But, for some reason, these values are not getting pulled in. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to add the `appsettings.json` to the `WebApplicationBuilder` like: `builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);` ?

Comment: That did fix it. This is just a pet project, I have never had to add that to any API before that went to prod. Why haven't I needed it before? Why does it work locally without this? Is there a way to do this without adding that code? Right now, I have it pointing to `D:\GitLocal\CrudMetrics\bin\Publish\appsettings.json`, which means that when developing locally, it would need to be published first, and two, I am not able to take advantage of `appsettings.development.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are running the app from another location then the `./Publish/` folder. The location of the `appsetings.json` is supposed to be in the location from where you are starting the application.

Try running `dotnet CrudMetrics.Api.dll --urls "https://localhost:7279"`from the `Publish` folder.

Comment: Thank you! `cd D:\GitLocal/CrudMetrics/bin/Publish` then running it worked without needing to do `builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);`.